# Rails + Simple_form_for: How to separated output of "f.association" in two columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, associations, simple-form

I have an associations that I use this way:

```
<%= f.association :cars, as: :check_boxes, 
                         label_method: :label, 
                         value_method: :id,
                         label: 'Cars' %>
```

It's working well, but aesthetically, it doesn't look really well. I would like to arrange checkboxes into two columns.

How to do that?

Thank you

Comment: `arrange checkboxes into two columns` means?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this is probably just to add an item-wrapper class and then style the checkbox container how you want. Maybe with a set width and a float.

```
<%= f.association :cars, as: :check_boxes, 
                     label_method: :label, 
                     value_method: :id,
                     label: 'Cars',
                     item_wrapper_class: 'car-checkbox-container' %>
```

Then in your stylesheet...

```
.car-checkbox-container {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```